# not being able to get apex element id in javascript method

Tags: javascript, inputfield, onchange

I am trying to access the id of an apex:inputfield tag within a script method.

The inputfield is within an apex:repeat variable.

I am trying to use the dollar component to access the id of the input field but it returns as null. Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong.

```
<script>
    function abc(){
        console.clear();
        var a= '{!$Component.enddate}';
        alert(document.getElementById(a));

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please share `HTML` code as well;

Comment: @Rimii, please check if any of the below answers helped you resolve your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find that trying to query by Id is challenging to do accurately in Visualforce. Instead, just use an HTML passthrough attribute and query on that instead.

```
<!-- Visualforce element you want -->
<apex:inputField html-data-some-value="abc" />
```

---

```
// In JavaScript
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-some-value='abc']");
```

Depending on specifically what you're trying to do (e.g. get a specific row), you can vary the attribute's value, or include a row index, or some other technique.

This technique works in jQuery, and on all browsers that are in the supported browsers list (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox).

Comment: I tried using this, but when I put an alert with the variable input, it shows [object NodeList] . I want to get the value of data-some-value='abc'. Is it possible by document.getElementById(inputs) ???

Answer (score 0):

From the **[docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm)**:

> If your component is nested, you might need to use a more complete component path specifier [...]

Like this example:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="theSection" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItem">
                <apex:outputText id="theText">
                    Heya!
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Then you need to do this:

`document.getElementById({!$Component.theBlock.theSection.theSectionItem.theText});`

Try naming all your hierarchy. It will make your life easier when referencing your individual components.

Comment: @RenatoOlveira, It is nested. That is the problem. The inputfield component is within an apex repeat tag which has a dynamic id. So I will not be able to hardcode it.